# Can't turn single pixel on on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, pixel

I have the following component in my react app:

```
<Grid container direction="column" justify="center" alignItems="center" item lg={12}>
  <canvas id="canvas" style={{border: '1px solid #000000', minHeight: '89%', minWidth: '99%'}} />
</Grid>
```

And I am using `fillRect()` to paint some pixels in it:

```
for(let i=-1; i<2; i++) {
  for(let j=-1; j<2; j++) {
    if (seedContent[i+1][j+1] === '1') {
      ctx.fillRect(centerPoint[0]+j, centerPoint[1]+i, 1, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the resulting image is not composed by single pixels, but a zoomed like pixeled image:
[image]

If I reduce the size of the canvas, like this:

```
<Grid container direction="column" justify="center" alignItems="center" item lg={12}>
  <canvas id="canvas" style={{border: '1px solid #000000', minHeight: '10%', minWidth: '10%'}} />
</Grid>
```

I get an image composed by single pixels, that is what I want:
[image]

How can I work on single pixels on large canvas?

**EDIT**
I found that if I set canvas like this:

```
<Grid container direction="column" justify="center" alignItems="center" item lg={12}>
  <canvas id="canvas" width='1200' height='600' border="1px solid #FFFFFF" />
</Grid>
```

I get the result I want, but I have to set a fixed size:

[image]

Comment: Possibly that 3rd and 4th param are width and height on Base 0. So should be `0, 0`.? Otherwise you get a 2px rect

Comment: @GetSet If you mean 3rd and 4th parameter of `fillRect()`, nope. I changed them as you say, and got the same result.

Comment: What happens if you make 3rd and 4th params same as 1st and 2nd? ... What does the docs say on 3rd and 4th params be a better question?

Comment: @GetSet I get a huge rectangle, 25% of the canvas covering the bottom right quadrant. Document says last two parameters are width and height of the rectangle.

Comment: Yeah i would have thought so :) ... So the 3rd and 4th is on dimension of the rectangle. 0, 0 would imply one pixel. What exactly is the discrepancy? On zoom in you mention?

Comment: well, if I put 0, 0, I get no pixels at all.

Comment: Is there a an "outline" pattern set, and possibly no "fill" pattern?